# Link error when using friend function in template linkedlist

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, linker-errors, friend

I programmed a template linked list(in .h file) and I get link error.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int size;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    inline T* Front() {return &(this->head);};
    inline const T* Front() const {return (const T*)this->head;};
    void InsertFirst(const T&);
    void InsertLast(const T&);
    void RemoveFirst();
    void RemoveLast ();
    void RemoveItem (const T&);
    void Sort();
    void Clear();
    inline bool Exists(const T&) const;
    bool Empty() const {return this->size==0 ? true : false;};
    inline int Size() const {return this->size;};
    T* At(const int index);
    const T* At(int index) const; 
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& that);
    T* operator[](const int);
    const T* operator[](const int) const;   
};
.
.
.

template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& that)
{
    if (!that.Empty())
        for(Node<T>* seeker=that.head; seeker; seeker=seeker->next)
            out<<seeker->info<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

For some reason the link error disappears when I write instead in the declaration of the friend function in the class:

```
template <typename T> friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& that);
```

Comment: Seems you answered yourself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the thing: the friend you declared is not a template, so the given instantiation of your << template isn't the one you declared friend.

If you declare the friend like this

```
template <typename U> //or T, doesn't matter
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<U>& that);
```

then `operator << <int>` will be a friend of `LinkedList<float>`. If that is undesirable, there is this solution:

```
friend ostream& operator <<<T> (ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& that);
```

In this case, only the particular instantiation of the template is your friend, which might be what you need.

[This article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc16friends_and_templates.htm) explains the topic in detail

Answer (score 4):

Because the definition of `operator<<` outside the class is *actually* a function template, whereas the friend declaration inside the class is not function template.

The `friend` declaration is a non-template function, and its arguments are fixed with respect to the class template.

For example, if you instantiate the class template with `int`, then the `friend` becomes this:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<int>& that);
```

which tells the compiler that *"I'm a friend of this class, I'm also a non-template function and you will find my defintion outside the class, exactly with same signature.".* You can see the arguments are fixed.

But when you do something like this:

```
template <typename U>
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<U>& that);
```

It makes sense to the compiler, as it is consistent with the definition of `operator<<` outside the class, which is also a function template. But there is a problem: it makes every specialization of the function template a friend of the class; means when `U=float`, the `operator<<` can access private members of `LinkedList<int>` as well, when it should be able to access private members of `LinkedList<float>` ONLY.  So you see, this is the problem.

A better solution would be this: DO NOT make it function template, and define the friend inside the class itself.

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
  public:


  friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList<T>& that)
  {
      //definition 
  }
};
```